# Перевод html hex таблицы в ascii файл

Tags: javascript, html, hex

[image: Вот таблица]
Мне надо на js написать код, который бы брал hex числа с ячеек, потом переводил их в двоичку и записал в файл в кодировке ASCII.

```
function download() 
{
    var str="";
    var str1="";//
    var arr = [];//
    var vrows = document.getElementsByName("data");//получаем массив ячеек
    for(var c=0;c<vrows.length;c++)//идем в цикле
    {
        str1="0x"+vrows[c].innerHTML;//заносим в массив значения ячеек и         добавляем 0x
        arr.push(parseInt(str1,16));//парсим в инт
        str+=String.fromCharCode(parseInt(str1,16));//соибраем строку из символов
    }

    alert (str);//выводим (для себя)
    var blob = new Blob([str], {//создаем файл и сохраняем
        type: "application/octet-stream"});//
    saveAs(blob, "core.bin");//
}
```

Я уже и пробовал переводить в двоичку из 16 и сохранять, и что только не пробовал. Не выходит. Сохраняет в UTF8 и коверкает текст...

Answer (score 1):

**Во-первых,**
 Вы хотите странного.
`ASCII` это семибитная кодировка. В `ASCII` 128 символов. То есть 00-7F - это стандартный `ASCII`. И `ASCII` -текст это валидный `UTF-8`, одни и те же коды символов. `ASCII` везде один и тот же.

Но Вы хотите символы 7F-FF, и это уже восьмибитная кодировка, так называемая [`Extended ASCII`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII). Не конкретная кодировка, а их семейство. И UTF-8 к этому семейству относится. Как и относятся большинство кодировок, в которых первые 128 символов такие же как в `ASCII`. И неплохо бы определиться, какая Вам нужна, если она не `UTF-8`. `String.fromCharCode` возвращает символ из `UTF-8` таблицы.

**Во-вторых,**
мне неизвестно способа указать браузеру в какой кодировке ему скачиваемый файл сохранять. Вполне вероятно что его пока нет. Но кодировка, это всего лишь подсказка для программы которая с данными работает, как эти данные понимать.

**В-третьих,**
В данном случае Вы можете просто открыть сохраненный файл в любом текстовом редакторе который умеет работать с кодировками и сказать редактору в какой кодировке понимать данный файл. Потому что никаких необратимых изменений самих данных по пути не было.